# ORA-00904: invalid identifier from PL/SQL code while the SQL part within works

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I defined a PL/SQL function in SQL developer and tried to run it, it returned "ORA-00904: "SYS"."FUNC1": invalid identifier;00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"", which isn't very helpful. I don't know what has gone wrong. The SQL part alone can run though.

- the PL/SQL that return error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1 (
    emp_id IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER AS
    emp_fname VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        firstname
    INTO emp_fname
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE
        employeeid = emp_id;

    RETURN emp_fname;
END func1;
/

select sys.func1(9) from dual;
```

- the SQL that run

```sql
    SELECT
        firstname
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE
        employeeid = 9;
```

- Definition of Table Employees

```
Name            Null?    Type          
--------------- -------- ------------- 
EMPLOYEEID      NOT NULL NUMBER        
LASTNAME        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)  
FIRSTNAME       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)  
TITLE                    VARCHAR2(30)  
TITLEOFCOURTESY          VARCHAR2(25)  
BIRTHDATE                DATE          
HIREDATE                 DATE          
ADDRESS                  VARCHAR2(60)  
CITY                     VARCHAR2(15)  
REGION                   VARCHAR2(15)  
POSTALCODE               VARCHAR2(10)  
COUNTRY                  VARCHAR2(15)  
HOMEPHONE                VARCHAR2(24)  
EXTENSION                VARCHAR2(4)   
PHOTO                    LONG RAW      
NOTES                    VARCHAR2(600) 
REPORTSTO                NUMBER        
PHOTOPATH                VARCHAR2(255)
```

Please help!

---

Test environment:

- OS: Oracle Linux 7.9
- Oracle DB 21c Express Edition for Linux
- SQL Developer for Linux 21.2.1.204 build 204.1703

Comment: Whoa! first off, never, ever create any objects in the SYS schema. Please edit the question and show the definition of the employees table.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The table definition has been updated.  I downloaded the express edition of oracle database and was instructed to use the `sys` user. I have no idea what else user can I use?

Comment: Did you create the function in the SYS schema (that is, while you were logged in as SYS)? Or did you create it in your own schema, but called it as `SYS.func1`?  The latter would be a very simple explanation of what happened: call it **without** the prefix `SYS`, which doesn't belong there anyway.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. actually I already noticed that obvious mistake after posting and removed the `sys.`; however, nothing changed.  i just starting learning pl/sql with the 19c xe vm downloaded from oracle, and it comes with the `sys` user. I haven't figured out how to create a user with a few attempts reporting failure.

Comment: @everwisher based on your comments about failures when creating users it sounds like the tutorial you are following is from before Multitenant became the standard in Oracle. You should now be working purely inside pluggable databases not the root container (which is what you’d connect to when you connect with oracle_sid). This is more than should be covered in a passing comment so make sure you are following tutorials written with pluggable (multitenant) databases in mind (anything below Oracle 12c definitely won’t cover it)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `SYS` as a work area. If you mess with any of the system tables then you may make your database unusable.

Use the `SYS` user to create a new user and then work in that user's schema.

---

Your function compiles successfully; however, it will fail at runtime (except for those rare people who are known by numbers and not names)  as the signature is `RETURN NUMBER` but it returns the `firstname` which is a string and you would get the exception:

> ```
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_RAHCBFZAHWTUCSZNOWGB.FUNC1", line 14
> ```

You can fix it by making the return type the same as the `firstname` column and the simplest method is to use `%TYPE`. You also ought to handle a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1 (
  emp_id IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID%TYPE
) RETURN EMPLOYEES.FIRSTNAME%TYPE
AS
  emp_fname VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  SELECT firstname
  INTO   emp_fname
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employeeid = emp_id;

  RETURN emp_fname;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END func1;
/
```

If you have the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees (employeeid, lastname, firstname)
VALUES (9, 'Abbots', 'Alice');
```

Then:

```sql
select func1(9) from dual;
```

Outputs:

> | FUNC1(9) |
> | --- |
> | Alice |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b0789e08d1f6bda656bc887d5fb19a25)*

Comment: Thank you so much for having explained my question in such detail, and brought me a superb alternative to SQL Developer! 

Actually I found the quirk that led to my previous failure. Whenever I make any change to the function, I have to click the run button (¿to recompile the function?) before I run the SQL statement that calls the function, which I didn't do but the tutorial didn't mention either.